# Ionic: Customizing a header button image

Tags: javascript, html, css, ionic-framework

I'm trying to add a customized image to a header button image in Ionic framework.

Here is my html in index.html:

```
<ion-nav-buttons side="right">
<button  ng-src="cartImage" ng-click="login()">
</button>
```

and in app.js I have:

```
  $scope.cartImage = "img/cart.png";
```

but despite the image being there, no dice, I just get a gray button. Is this even the right way of setting an header button in Ionic? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the [AngularJS ngSrc documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSrc), `ng-src` was made specifically to deal with the inability to use Angular expressions within a `src` attribute (such as `{{ photoUrl }}` in an actual URL string).

If you're going to use ngSrc and you want to drop a scope variable in there, you need to use an expression:

```
<button ng-src="{{ cartImage }}" ng-click="login()"></button>
```